# Getting values from one specific table from a website

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I am trying to get the average price from [this website](https://yugiohprices.com/card_price?name=Triple+Tactics+Talent). From the "2021 Tin of Ancient Battles --MP21-EN143', the table is below the "Picture Not Available" image.
[image: Orange Box outlines the able I am interested in]

When I use the following code, I just get content from the first table at the top of the URL, the able underneath "Tournament Eligibility".

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://yugiohprices.com/card_price?name=Triple+Tactics+Talent'
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
table = soup.findAll('table',{'id':'item_stats'})
print(table)
```

Is it that my code is not waiting long enough for the entire website to load? I tried waiting for 5 seconds after I request the url, but it still shows the first table at the top. Any suggestions for how to get this value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What happens?

Site is dynamically loading the content you like to get - Cause requests could not simulate browser behavior, it do not work to wait?

#### How to fix?

Information comes from another url, you can choose this:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.94 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://yugiohprices.com/get_card_prices/Triple%20Tactics%20Talent'
r = requests.get(url, headers= headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
soup.select('table#item_stats tr:nth-of-type(3) td')[1].text
```

Alternativ and maybe better solution if you like to go deeper is [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage) so you can simulate a browser.